# Can't get Out argument from WorkflowApplication

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow with an In/Out argument and I'm not getting it back in the WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs.Outputs.

I have 2 Arguments:

```
  DataParams which is In/Out
  ClassParams which is In
```

I'm calling the workflow like this:

```
  IDictionary<string, object> inParams = new Dictionary<string, object>
  {
    {"DataParams", _dataParameters },
    {"ClassParams", _classParameters },
  };


  workflowApp = new WorkflowApplication(new actSendToClient(), inParams);
  workflowApp.Completed = e => SendToClientWorkflowCompleted(e);
  workflowApp.Run();
```

Some time later if the user cancels this method in the host is called:

```
workflowApp.Cancel();
```

which routes to the delegated method:

```
public void SendToClientWorkflowCompleted(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var output = e.Outputs;
}
```

I get nothing in e.Outputs.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Who knows?  Do you have an OutArgument defined on the root Activity?  Cancel may be called before it is updated, so this makes sense.  Or are you expecting your `inParams` to be in `e.Outputs`?  That won't happen.  You'll have to hang onto a reference if you need them later.

Comment: Doh! Hang on to a reference.  Sometimes I'm soooo stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You only get output arguments if the workflow runs to a good end. And when you cancel the workflow you are telling it not do so. If you need a way to stop a workflow half way through the process and it is still considered a normal end of job you will need to model this in you workflow in some way. Either by explicitly adding logic to circumvent part of the activities or by throwing and exception and adding the extra data to the exception thrown. In the latter case the runtime can check the exception and see get the data from there.

Normally I prefer the first approach if this is really part of the business process.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you want the output arguments to be valid in the cancelation path, you can wrap your root activity in a CancellationScope that sets the OutArguments in the CancellationHandler.

One more note, the value of an OutArgument reflects the state of that argument within the workflow. That is, if you populate the OutArgument mid-way through your activity, those values will be reflected in the OutArgument. This is consistent with C# out arguments that are assigned to and then the method subsequently throws an exception.